# Ant colony optimization method

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, discrete-optimization, optimal-control

if i have an equation like
            $$f_n = x + y + z + a + b$$ 
and each variable has a discrete answer like $a = 0, 1 , 3$ . $b = 2 ,4,5$ etc.
i want to find the global optimum minimization point. I used Ant colony optimization (ACO) to solve the equation but i am stuck in the heuristic information and how to compute these parameters, as I saw in the traveling sale's man problem eta = one over distance between two cities. But here there is no relation between $x$ and $y$ .

Second i want to make sure that when computing $\delta_\tau$ pheromone updating trail , its equal to $$f_n(\text{best answer in iteration k})\over f_n(\text{worth answer in iteration k})$$ as i saw another equations in papers and got distracted. 
I built a matlab model but it didn't give me the optimum point at each run time . 
Thank you

Comment: You should use mathjax syntax.

Comment: You need to use "integer programming" to optimize a system in which the variables are discrete.

Comment: Please, I need more explanation @AndrewGray

Comment: Done, Thank you @Furrane

Comment: Just to clarify: all of $x,y,z,a,b$ are discrete variables?

Comment: yes, they are discrete variables. @user3658307
I used ACO to find the shortest path as the equation above is just an example but in reality the equation has 100 variable and could be more depending on the loads connected. The problem i face is that i need to figure out the correct parameters that i have to use. and to make sure that the second equation is true . Please, if you have a recommended material to guide me , mention it.

Comment: It seems a little confusing (to me anyway) what exactly you are asking. My first inclination in such cases are methods like [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) or [genetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm). Adding some more details might help others answer the question.

Comment: Its network dynamic load balancing based on ACO @user3658307